# Canvas Xpress Sample Code..?

Tags: canvas, express

I'm trying to get started with Canvas Xpress, but I'm not very familiar with javascript, and I'm getting stuck with syntax.

Can someone show me a sample basic code that would just put a sample canvas on an blank page?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can always take a look at the official documentation at http://canvasxpress.org/documentation.html